# Mysql Select INNER JOIN with order by very slow

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-order-by, inner-join

I'm trying to speed up a mysql query. The Listings table has several million rows. If I don't sort them later I get the result in 0.1 seconds but once I sort it takes 7 seconds. What can I improve to speed up the query?

```
SELECT l.* 
FROM listings l 
INNER JOIN listings_categories lc 
ON l.id=lc.list_id 
AND lc.cat_id='2058' 
INNER JOIN locations loc 
ON l.location_id=loc.id 
WHERE l.location_id 
IN (7841,7842,7843,7844,7845,7846,7847,7848,7849,7850,7851,7852,7853,7854,7855,7856,7857,7858,7859,7860,7861,7862,7863,7864,7865,7866,7867,7868,7869,7870,7871,7872,7873,7874,7875,7876,7877,7878,7879,7880,7881,7882,7883,7884,7885,7886,7887,7888,7889,7890,7891,7892,7893,7894,7895,7896,7897,7898,7899,7900,7901,7902,7903) 
ORDER BY date 
DESC LIMIT 0,10;
```

EXPLAIN SELECT: Using Index l=date, loc=primary, lc=primary

Comment: Why join with locations in the first place, no value from locations is used and the location_id is queried with the in expression...

Comment: Which table is `date` in?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Comment: @Turo - Presumably that is how the OP limits the results to those locations.

Comment: @RickJames the locations are already limited through the `IN` predicate, it would be a very bad design if there were location_ids in listings without record in location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such performance questions are really difficult to answer and depend on the setup, indexes etc. So, there will likely not the one and only solution and even not really correct or incorrect attempts to improve the speed. This is a lof of try and error. Anyway, some points I noted which often cause performance issues are:

- Avoid conditions within joins that should be placed in the where instead. A join should contain the columns only that will be joined, no further conditions. So the "lc.cat_id='2058" should be put in the where clause.
- Using IN is often slow. You could try to replace it by using OR (l.location_id  = 7841 OR location_id = 7842 OR...)
- Open the query execution plan and check whether there is something useful for you.
- Try to find out if there are special cases/values within the affected columns which slow down your query
- Change "ORDER BY date" to "ORDER BY tablealias.date" and check if this makes a difference in performance. Even if not, it is better to read.
- If you can rename the column "date", do this because using SQL keywords as table name or column name is no good idea. I'm unsure if this influences the performance, but it should be avoided if possible.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. MySQL took an incorrect index. The IGNOR INDEX command worked for me. The query takes now only 0.002 seconds

Answer (score 0):

You can try additonal indexes to speed up the query, but you'll have a tradeoff when creating/manipulating data.

These combined keys could speed up the query:

```
listings: date, location_id 
listings_categories: cat_id, list_id
```

Since the plan says it uses the date index, there wouldn't be a need to read the record to check the location_id when usign the new index, and same for the join with listinngs_category, index read would be enough

Answer (score 0):

```
l:  INDEX(location_id, id)
lc:  INDEX(cat_id, list_id)
```

If those don't suffice, try the following rewrite.

```
SELECT  l2.*
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT  l1.id
            FROM  listings AS l1
            JOIN  listings_categories AS lc  ON lc.list_id = l1.id
            JOIN  locations AS loc  ON loc.id = l1.location_id
            WHERE  lc.cat_id='2058'
              AND  l1.location_id IN (7841, ..., 7903)
            ORDER BY  l1.date DESC
            LIMIT  0,10 
    ) AS x
    JOIN  listings l2  ON l1.id = x.id
    ORDER BY  l2.date DESC
```

With

```
listings:  INDEX(location_id, date, id)
listings_categories:  INDEX(cat_id, list_id)
```

The idea here is to get the 10 ids from the index before reaching to the table itself.  Your version is probably shoveling around the whole table before sorting, and then delivering the 10.